# Deal with methods that have same parameter types and avoid issues due to pass params in wrong order

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, methods, arguments

When we have a method that accepts arguments of same type we could have the problem of passing the arguments in wrong order i.e. swapped

Example `int someMethod(int a, int b)`
And the caller calls the method with `someMethod(b,a)` instead. I think that there is a design pattern to avoid this issues.Am I right?
What is it?

Comment: How it can be avoided?Design patterns are there to solve the stuff which actually is a problem not to solve the stuff which is not an issue itself.There is something that  needs to be done by developer :)

Comment: instead of individual variables send an object to the method

Comment: Don't I have the same problem with the constructor of the object now?

Comment: I believe that naming parameters and variables in code may reduce chances of such a mistake. If you have a method someMethod(int radius, int angle) and the programmer uses variables "radius" and "angle" then IDE like Eclipse is likely to suggest correct argument order based on parameter and variable name.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are referring to named parameters, which Java does not support. The best alternative would be to use an object to wrap the parameters.

```
int someMethod(SomeBean bean);

...

SomeBean bean = new SomeBean();
bean.setA(1);
bean.setB(2);
someMethod(bean);
```

Comment: But even this does not stop one from setting the swapped values on the bean object.

Comment: Unit testing maybe? Builder pattern? EnterpriseSomeBeanServiceLocatorFacoryServiceBuilderFactoryBeanCreatorService?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enum` if there is a clear specification of acceptable values for the method arguments.

```
enum ValuesA {
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4);
    private int val;
    ValuesA(int val) {this.val = val;}
    int val() {return val;}
}

enum ValuesB {
    TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6);
    private int val;
    ValuesB(int val) {this.val = val;}
    int val() {return val;}
}
```

With this your `someMethod` needs to be modified as well:

```
int someMethod(ValuesA a, ValuesB b)
```

Which will be invoked like this:

```
someMethod(ValuesA.ONE, ValuesB.FOUR)
```

And inside the method you will have to get the `int` values with `val()`: `a.val()`, `b.val()`..

Of course this applies only when you already know the sets of allowed values for `a` and `b` and the sets aren't too big.

Another limitation is the inability to use variables during method invocations.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a parameter list where the parameters are related and this relation dictates valid sets of values that can be passed together, you may be best off creating a class that understands those validity rules, and pass that instead of the parameter list.

For example, if your method signature is

```
int someMethod(int low, int high)
```

and you want to disallow a call such as

```
int z = someMethod(10, 6);
```

because the values are in the wrong order, you might want to create a `Range` class, approximately as follows:

```
public class Range {

    private int low;
    private int high;

    public Range(int low, int high) {
        super();
        if (high < low)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid range");
        this.low = low;
        this.high = high;
    }

    public int getLow() {
        return low;
    }

    public int getHigh() {
        return high;
    }
}
```

and change the signature of your method to

```
int someMethod(Range range)
```

so that you can only pass it an already constructed and valid range.

If the relation is something else, of course you'd make a different class to capture different rules.